# How to use Dto?

Tags: c#, .net, dto

I have a class like this .I want to get movie details but I don't want to show Id.

```
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int View { get; set; }
    public DateTime RelaseDate { get; set; }
}
```

I have MoveDto class but I don't know how to use dto class in my MovieManager

```
public class MovieDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Overview { get; set; }
    public DateTime RelaseDate { get; set; }
}
```

And This is my MovieManager

```
public class MovieManager:IMovieService
{
    private IMovieDal _movieDal;
    public MovieManager(IMovieDal movieDal)
    {
        _movieDal = movieDal;
    }


    public Movie GetMovieDetail(int movieId)
    {
        
       // How can i fill here?

    }
}
```

Please help

Comment: "but I don't want to show Id" show where? Why?

Comment: what's the content of interface IMovieDal?

Comment: I don't want the id to come while the movie details are coming . MovieDal have a crud operations .

Comment: You don't want to show `Movie.Id` from `MovieManager.GetMovieDetail`? Make it return a `MovieDto`, not a  `Movie`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have said, your MovieManager will need to look up the Movie within the method body and then map it to a MovieDto and return that Dto.